# Problem with ADC in AVR XMEGA

Tags: audio, noise, processing, white

I am using an Xmega32A4U
I convert an audio with ADC and after processing it sends out with DAC.
I checked Power supply and try all of parameter to use ADC but it is a big problem and the audio out covered with a white noise.

After measure ADC conversion to a USART I see it have 10 difference output  value in a fixed dc input.
I try it with ATmega8 and maximum difference value is 2 number but it's so slow for audio processing.
If I can reduce tolerance of conversion result to 3?

Comment: The question isn't really clear. Could you give an example? What are your values representing?

Answer (score 0):

Datasheet noise level (typical only) is given:

[image]

Reference voltage is not stated. If we assume it's 3.6V then the resolution is 0.8mV and we'd expect to see about 4 different values with the input shorted.

However with a non-zero DC voltage applied then other noise sources come into play. Depending on your conditions (and layout) 10 different values is not unexpected.

I think if you want decent quality audio capture you should use a separate audio ADC, maybe with I2S interface.

Alternatively, maybe you could capture 8 samples (say) and average them to reduce the noise by perhaps 2 or 3:1.